# Showing the existence of $O^{\pi}(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Assume G is a finite group.  I am trying to show the existence of $O^{\pi}(G)$, the unique normal subgroup of G minimal such that $G/O^{\pi}(G)$ is a $\pi$-group, i.e. a group whose order is divisible only by primes in the set $\pi$.  I would just like to check that I have a proof.

Let $N=\langle \,g \in G\,|\, \gcd(|g|,p)=1 \,\,\forall \ p \in \pi \,\rangle$.

Normality is easy: each element of $N$ is a product of elements with order coprime to every prime in $\pi$.  Let $xy$ be such an element (this is readily extended to larger products).  Then $g^{-1}xyg=g^{-1}xgg^{-1}yg \in N$ since conjugation preserves orders.

Minimality: Suppose $M \le N$ and $M \triangleleft G$.  Then by the third isomorphism theorem, $G/N \cong (G/M)/(N/M)$.  Since $G/N$ and $G/M$ are $\pi$-groups by assumption, $N/M$ must also be a $\pi$-group.  Intuitively, since modding by $M$ must kill all 'non-$\pi$' elements of $N$, it must have as a generating set $\{g \in G\,|\, \gcd(|g|,p)=1 \,\,\forall \ p \in \pi\}$, so $M = N$.  Does this work?

Uniqueness: Similarly (maybe this follows from the above argument), if $|M|=|N|$ and $G/M$ is a $\pi$-group, then $M$ must contain $\{g \in G\,|\, \gcd(|g|,p)=1 \,\,\forall \ p \in \pi\}$, so $M=N$ and $N$ must be unique.

Helpful critiques are welcome.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is finite?  If $G$ can be infinite then there are broad gaps in this proof.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: Yes, I forgot to add that G is assumed to be finite.  I will edit accordingly.

Comment: I might change the language a little bit, but at least at first glance this looks good to me.

Comment: Thanks.  I would like to see the details on the minimality argument.  I really was just going by intuition and I am uncertain of the technical details.

Comment: Yeah, on second reading the 'intuitively' does come out a little bit fuzzy. I think that might need a little more detail, but I'll have to chew about it some.

Comment: Basically all right, but you could argue as follows: Let $M\unlhd G$ and $G/M$ is a $\pi$-group. Then $M$ must contain ..., hence $M\geq N$. So, $N$ is contained in any $M$ s.t. ... Thus $N$ is a unique...

Comment: @AlexW Is $N$ unique because it is the intersection of all such $M$?  Does this also show that $N$ is minimal?

Comment: Yes. Also, let $N'$ be any minimal co-$\pi$-subgroup, then, as we already know, $N\leq N'$ and by minimality of $N'$ we get $N=N'$.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.

Comment: I prefer to define subgroups of this type in other way, through the intersections and injection to direct products. It allows us to define, for example, co-abelian radical, co-solvable radical, co-nilpotent radical and so on in the same way.

Comment: By 'co-blah radical' do you just mean the minimal (sometimes maximal?) normal subgroup such that quotienting by it gives us a blah group?  I see how the intersection is the nicer way to obtain these groups.  What is the relationship to direct products?

Comment: You did not use the @ sign, so I just saw your message ) I use the fact, that if $(N_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of normal subgroups of $G$, then $G/\bigcap_{i\in I}N_i$ embedded in $\underset{i\in I}{\times}(G/N_i)$. Hence if $\mathcal C$ is a class of groups, closed under subgroups and decart products, then we can define $O^{\mathcal C}(G)$ as intersection of all co-$\mathcal C$-subgroups of $G$. Then $O^{\mathcal C}(G)$ will be a unique minimal co-$\mathcal C$-subgroup of $G$.